# Nested virtual machine internet connection

Tags: networking, vmware

I am running a Debian virtual Machine (Sue)  on VMWare, which has one virtual machine inside

it (called Billy - I can enter it with (vzctl enter 100) ).

I want to be able to access the internet on Billy via Sue (I have set some restrictions on Sue 
with iptables, and I want to at the same time I want to check the traffic between Billy and the internet).

How do I do this ? Should I use a bridge ? Or IP Forwarding? Thank you!

Comment: I love your avatar.

Comment: This is how I feel when I gave to do networking.

Comment: linux server networking dudes are gone for the weekend here, and I'm clueless when it comes to this, sorry.  See you in mid later :P